# Test for HttpPost service: how to take JSON body for test?

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest, post, httppost

I have a HttpPost methods. And I really don't know how to test it correctly.

My methods:

```
public static App__c ParseRequest(RestRequest req) {
    App__c app = new App__c();
    String body = req.requestBody.toString();
    app = (App__c)JSON.deserialize(body, App__c.class);
    return app;  
} 

@HttpPost
global static Id doPost() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;        
    App__c app = ParseRequest(req);
    insert app;
    return app.id;
}
```

My test (just basis):

```
public static String GenerateJSON(App__c a){
    Map<String, String> fieldMap = new Map<String, String>{'Title__c' => a.Name};       
    String serialized = JSON.serialize(fieldMap);         
    return serialized;
}

@isTest
static void testPost() {
    App__c record = createTestRecord();
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
    request.requestUri = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/apexrest/App__c/' + record.Id;
    request.httpMethod = 'POST';
    RestContext.request = request;

    record = (App__c)JSON.deserialize(GenerateJSON(record), App__c.class);

    App__c j = Endpoint.ParseRequest(request);
    record = (App__c)JSON.deserialize(body, App__c.class);
}

static App__c createTestRecord() {
    App__c app = new App__c(
        Title__c = 'Title',
    );
    insert app;
    return app;
}
```

In App__c j = `Endpoint.ParseRequest(request);` I become `Argument cannot be null.` without coverage of:

```
    app = (App__c)JSON.deserialize(body, App__c.class);
    return app;  
} 

@HttpPost
global static Id doPost() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;        
    App__c app = ParseRequest(req);
    insert app;
    return app.id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only real differences between testing an Apex webservice, and testing a "normal" Apex class is that you'll be providing input via `RestContext.request`, and gathering output via `RestContext.response`.

The following is an excerpt from one of my own tests for an Apex webservice in my org:

```
RestContext.request = new System.RestRequest();
RestContext.response = new System.RestResponse();
Map<String, String> headers = RestContext.request.headers;

headers.put('Content-Type', 'application/json');
RestContext.request.requestBody = Blob.valueOf('{}');
```

I set up the `RestContext` global...variable...thing with new instances of `RestRequest` and `RestResponse`, then store the request headers in a map.

Changes made to the `headers` map are automatically reflected in `RestContext.request.headers` (which is good, because I don't recall there being a `setHeaders()` method).

Finally, we set the request body (and we do need to directly assign this one), which accepts a `blob`. We can't construct a `blob` directly. We need to use the static method `Blob.valueOf(String)`. In the test method that I took this code from, I'm testing what happens when my webservice receives a null object. *Your test will likely be different*.

Probably the easiest way for you to generate the JSON that you'll pass to the class you're testing is to create an in-memory instance of `App__c` (i.e. don't insert this record yourself in your test class, let the class being tested do the inserting).

```
App__c myTestApp = new App__c(
    some_field__c = 'value',
    other_field__c = 'something else'
);

String appJson = JSON.serialize(myTestApp);
```

Then you can swap in your JSON string where I have my empty JSON object in `Blob.valueOf()`

The other parts of unit testing remain the same. The only notes that I want to make here are that:

1. You need to call the method you're testing, *directly* (i.e. explicitly call `doPost()`)
2. Take some time to think about *what the effects of calling `doPost()` are*, and write assertions (e.g. `System.assertEquals()`) to verify that *all* of those things are indeed happening